# How do you trigger Riddler buttons that are mounted on the wall?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with riddler trophies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35921/how-to-deal-with-riddler-trophies)

I've come across several Riddler puzzles that require pressing buttons that are mounted vertically against a wall.  I have tried several different methods for pressing them, including using the line launcher and tight rope walking to press my body into it, but nothing I have tried works.  What's the easiest technique for pressing these pads?

[image]

Comment: @Ullallulloo I had seen that question a couple days ago, but at that point hadn't come across any puzzles with the wall-mounted plates.  The accepted answer on that question makes no mention of the wall-mounted types, which are much different to activate than floor-mounted ones.  If someone would like to edit the accepted answer to the linked question, I'll vote to close

Comment: FallenAngelEyes' answer just below mentions them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to glide into the wall on the button. Batman will activate it, and you can push off and glide elsewhere. You'll want to start on top of a building then glide down to it.

Buttons on walls tend to turn up in sets of three, all of which need to be pressed without touching anything that's not a button. Don't be surprised if it turns off when you land.